# Google search not displaying the right title

Tags: html, seo, title

I made a hompage for a customer. Unfortunately, after hosting i realized that the title name of the page was wrong. So i edited it. The problem is that the google search is still showing the wrong title. Hoe to bring google to display the right title name?

the title name is the name of the Person, its a big problem when google is displaying his name wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either wait for Google to re-index it or try to raise a manual request from Google webmaster Tools but you must be the verified owner of the site ( from Google's perspective ) to do the second option.

EDIT: Adding helpful URLs
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing?hl=en

Comment: thx for answering. I am the Owner of the Site. i logged in to the google Webmaster Tools but cant find where to change it. Can you tell me where to find it?

Comment: I've added some useful URLs :)